# Is there a limit for number of times Ordinal Inscriptions can be transferred to a new address?

Tags: transaction-fees, utxo-set, ordinals

Ordinal Inscriptions are typically created by making 10000-satoshi UTXOs. To transfer the Inscription to a new address (when it's sold, for example), the UTXO is spent and transaction fee is paid, thus the next owner's UTXOs is less than 10000 satoshi. Can it happen that at some point, after multiple transfers, the Inscription becomes un-transferable because the UTXO amount is not enough to cover the transaction fee?

At the time of this writing, there are over 400K txs in mempool and TX fees are routinely ~2000 satoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if wallets mishandle it, you aren't supposed to subtract the transaction fee from the inscription's 10k sats, but pay it using an additional UTXO. In theory, it'll continue to have the same amount forever...